# Android EditText blocks its parent's OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

1) I create a number of controls dynamically. I have a medium-sized RelativeLayout with an EditText that fills most of its parent visible space. The rest is covered by another view and the layout is supposed to slide up on click. The problem is that **the layout does not receive onClick event when user clicks on the EditText**. I can't use TextView because I will need user to enter some text into it later. I tried this code, without success

```
private void addTopView() {
    RelativeLayout midView = new RelativeLayout(this);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wallet_top);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(scale(320), scale(heightTop));
    midView.addView(imageView, lp);
    RelativeLayout topCard = populateTPasses ? addTpass(0) : addCard(0);
    topCard.setOnClickListener(topCardClick);
    midView.addView(topCard);
    lp = new LayoutParams(scale(320), scale(cardTopOffsetY + cardHeight));
    lp.topMargin = scale(upperOffset);
    walletScrollView.addView(midView, lp);
}

private RelativeLayout addCard(int indexVal) {
    String cardName = "Add Credit Card";
    String cardNum = "Max 16 digits";
    String cardCVC = "Max 6 digits";
    boolean switchStatus = NO;
    String cardExpiry = dateFormatter.format(new Date());
    if(indexVal < creditcards.size())
    {
        cardName = creditcards.get(indexVal).name;
        cardNum = String.format("........%s", creditcards.get(indexVal).display);
        cardCVC = "NOT STORED";
        cardExpiry = creditcards.get(indexVal).expiry;
        switchStatus = creditcards.get(indexVal).isDefault;
    }
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(scale(cardWidth), scale(cardHeight));
    lp.leftMargin = scale(cardTopOffsetX);
    lp.topMargin = scale(cardTopOffsetY);
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    layout.setTag(indexVal);
    addCardElements(layout, cardName, cardNum, cardExpiry, cardCVC, switchStatus);
    return layout;
}

private ImageView addCardElements(RelativeLayout whichCard, String cardName, String cardNumber, String cardExpiry, String cardCVC, boolean defaultStatus) {
    whichCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.credit_card_tpay);

    //Add card name
    EditText cardNameField = addCardName(cardName);

    whichCard.addView(cardNameField);
    return null;
}

private EditText addCardName(String cName) {
    EditText cardName = new EditText(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(scale(cardWidth - 90), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.leftMargin = scale(32 + 50);
    params.topMargin = scale(15);
    cardName.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    cardName.setLayoutParams(params );
    cardName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    if(isLast == NO || (_selectedIndex >= creditcards.size() && creditcards.size() != 0))
        cardName.setText(cName);
    else
    {
        cardName.setHint(cName);
    }
    isLast = NO;
    cardName.setTag(kTag_CardName);
    if(_selectedIndex >= creditcards.size())
        cardName.setEnabled(YES);
    else {
        cardName.setEnabled(NO);
        cardName.setFocusable(NO);
        cardName.setFocusableInTouchMode(NO);
        cardName.setClickable(NO);
        cardName.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
    cardName.setGravity(5);
    return cardName;
}
```

2) **This one is solved.** *When my layout slides up with the help of TranslateAnimation I have to remove it from its parent and to put onto another ViewGroup or else all the user input gets broken. Then it slides back with similar change of parent. In the process I set the layout's OnClickListener to null and back to my listener. The problem is that after that the listener never fires and the layout can only slide once. I wonder what could be causing this.*

Comment: More code with the listener would help maybe.

Comment: The problem #2 was solved by moving the call to cancel animation *before* changing the layout parent. However the EditText still blocks its parent OnClickListener...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that a click on EditText does not propagate to it's parent, unlike a click on a TextView. You have to listen to the children themselves.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 problems:

First you need to add your "clickable" content before adding the EditText (to the RelativeLayout). You can do this either by adding them first or by specifying index = 0 when using `addView`.

The second problem is after a translate animation, you will need to change the layout params to the target location so that they can get the clicks. You can use an animation listener and upon the end of the animation update the layout params of the clickable content to the new location.

I can not really tell because you did not include the relevant code.

---

After your comment:

So you do not have the first problem because it seems your clickable view is showing above correctly after the animation. However, the second problem is what you have because even if they appear above it, their real position is still unchanged and that is why you do not get any touch event. You need to update their position (LayoutParams) after the animation ends.

Comment: I already have the animation listener and I do change the layout params. Can you clarify adding "clickable" content?

Comment: evetything is showing just fine. The problem is the click listener not firing, on two separate conditions